# Two extension methods with the same name and signature

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Call to

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Joonasw.AspNetCore.SecurityHeaders;

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseHsts();
}
```

causes an error:

`The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.HstsBuilderExtensions.UseHsts(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.IApplicationBuilder)' and 'Joonasw.AspNetCore.SecurityHeaders.AppBuilderExtensions.UseHsts(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.IApplicationBuilder)'`

I am using extension methods from both namespaces, so I cannot stop referencing one of them.

How can I continue using both namespaces and precisely tell the compiler which extension method I want?

Comment: just fully qualify it and call it as a normal method.